# 'Delete' method is not supported with Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

My controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/list/{fn}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Record> deleteUser(@PathVariable("fn")   String filename) {
   System.out.println("Fetching & Deleting data " + filename);

   Record user1 = rep.findByfilename(filename);
   if (user1 == null) {
       System.out.println("Unable to delete." + filename + " not found");
       return new ResponseEntity<Record>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
   }

   rep.deleteByfilename(filename);
   return new ResponseEntity<Record>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
}
```

My js code:

```
$scope.del = function (record) {
        if (confirm('Do you really want to delete?')){
             $http['delete']('/camera/list/' + record.filename).then(function() {
                 $scope.records.splice($scope.records.indexOf(record), 1);
          });
        }
      };
```

My access setting:

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/imageview", "/hello").access("hasRole('USER')")
    .antMatchers("/camera/list").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/camera/store").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/camera/list/{fn}").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/imageview2", "/hello2").access("hasRole('ADMIN')").and()
    .formLogin().and().exceptionHandling()
    .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");

    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll();
}
```

The error i'm getting is:

```
DELETE 
XHR 
http://localhost:8086/camera/list/a0c8918e4b088de4a5c7796e3eb11229 [HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed 22ms]
```

At first, my delete function can work but after i use spring security then i got this error that is not supported. Anybody can help? i tried searching online for help but no solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the problem by adding http.csrf().disable() to spring security access setting.

Answer (score 0):

Add [HiddenHttpMethodFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/HiddenHttpMethodFilter.html) to your web.xml.

Comment: I do not have web.xml file

Comment: Then in your class implementing WebApplicationInitializer

Comment: I assume you have either web.xml or SpringBootServletInitializer or some class implementing WebApplicationInitializer. I.e. something that tells the app server about Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a wildcard pattern like `/camera/list/**` for the antMatcher instead of the pattern used for defining the controller's config (`/camera/list/{fn}`) to allow access on the specific items.

Comment: Your controller class has assigned the `RequestMapping` for `/camera`, right? The method annotation only declares `/list/{fn}`. Be aware that Spring returns a 405 if you do something else than `GET` on an invalid url...

Comment: i think is spring security restrict me from using delete method.